# Get statistics on data inserts, updates in SAS log using pass through sql connecting to Teradata

Tags: sas, teradata

I am using SAS EG to connect to teradata to read/write destination tables. I am using pass through sql to connect to teradata. Since , this is explicit sql in SAS, i am not able to see details in logs such as record inserts to a table, updates(how many records got updated etc). Is there a way to get such information in sas logs? I know it is possible in data steps in sas but with above request i am not able to do so. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by explicit sql? Are you using SQL Pass through?

Comment: Yes pass through sql

Answer (score 1):

Options SASTRACE helps and you can try

```
       options sastrace=',,,d' sastraceloc=saslog nostsuffix;;
```

More info what the option logs and how you can effectively use SAS Trace with  Teradata connections can be found in ["Troubleshooting SAS and Teradata Query Performance Problems"](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/TroubleshootingSASandTeradataQueryPerformanceProblems.pdf), Jeffrey D. Bailey, 2010.

The documentation for `SASTRACE` option is found at:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000433982.htm

Comment: All above sas code, options sastrace did was to log all sql code in it. I am already getting that but wanted to see how many records were inserted ,updated, deleted etc in log. Above code does not help get that.